Reason for lost rep where multiple posts were removed in short timeframe
I just lost rep for these seven posts that were removed:

My initial assumption was that these were edits I made when I was a <2k rep user, and they were all associated with a single deleted account. However, to have so many happen at the same time made me think about the possibility that I may have erred somewhere in the review queues or something similar? The only meta posts I could find related to <2k rep users.
As I'm not sure whether deleted posts would even persist, combined with the unappealing thought of manually searching, I haven't looked in my edit history as yet.
I am just looking for clarity to ensure I am not creating unnecessary work for the mods.

"However, to have so many happen at the same time made me think about the possibility that I may have erred somewhere in the review queues or something similar" - This strikes me as an odd sequence of events. Your evidence is reputation loss. Why would you think review queues have anything to do with that? If I have to read between the lines here, it almost sounds like you think it might have been some form of a punishment for reviewing badly.

Looks like these questions were deleted by an automated process. See about Roomba
Look at this:

Or this:

Or this:

Or this:

Looks like a bunch of questions you edited around a year back, were abandoned, ignored by the community, and finally deleted by an automated process.
